# Filter a directive by using a div wrapper or within the directive tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to go with the best approach and avoid unnecessary rendering/processing time in my AngularJS app when choosing between 2 directives to be displayed in the page inside an ngRepeat loop, want to know which is the best way:

If by setting the `ng-if` directly in the directive html element, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in list"> 
    <my-directive-a ng-if="someFunction(element)"></my-directive-a>
    <my-directive-b ng-if="!someFunction(element)"></my-directive-b>
</div>
```

Or by moving out the first `<div>` from the directive's template and use it as a wrapper for each directive. For instance:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in list"> 
    <div ng-if="someFunction(element)">
        <my-directive-a></my-directive-a>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!someFunction(element)">
        <my-directive-b></my-directive-b>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: The starting `<div>` element on each directive could be modified behave the same so I will basically take that out of the directive's html and moving it outside the directive declaration in order to place the `ng-if` there

What would be the best approach for this case? Are there any performance implications from doing it one way or another? Or is it just the same thing? Consider that the number of elements in the list could get really big.

Comment: if list will be big...the less watchers in view the better. Since ng-if creates watches and child scopes might be better to off load the conditional to another directive that only has to evaluate `someFunction` once. More details on these directives would help

Answer (score 0):

They are quite the same, but you can improve performance with [one-time binding](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/), but only when `element` does not change at runtime (for example, let's say that it has property `name`, and your `someFunction` is like `return element.name === 'John'`). Angular just stop observing this function when it returns value, and watches will be deleted. There are 2 prerequisites to use this solution:

1. Elements properties in list does not change (if you rely on them in `someFunction`), for example if you rely on `name` property name must not change, because watcher on `someFunction` is note available.
2. When list changes or its elements properties change, you reload all list (for example, you fetch it from server again if you know that change occurred)

What you get with this? There is no watches after `my-directive`s are drawn on `ng-if`s, and when something changes, new reference is bound to `list` (for example, it comes from server) and everything will be redrawn, `ng-if`s will run again and when will become stable (function returns value) then will be unbound. How it looks like? Like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in list"> 
    <div ng-if="::(someFunction(element))">
        <my-directive-a></my-directive-a>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="::(!someFunction(element))">
        <my-directive-b></my-directive-b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Two colons before expression. But be aware, that with one-time binding it's easy to mess up - you need to be sure that you test your code enough to be sure it works.